# BackboneJS How to detect mobile page setup

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone App with the following structure

```
rootfolder
  - assets
  - js
    app
    - app.js
    - router.js
    - config.js
    modules
    - all my views in this folder
    templates
    - all my html templates here
- node_modules
- mobilepages (folder with all mobile pages, e.g. mobile BackboneJS setup)
```

How can I detect mobile users and load the mobilepages folder? Do I have to do this with the router?

Something like this?:

```
return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    }

    index: function(){
      if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
      {
        this.navigate("/mobilepages", {replace:true})
      };        
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any functional difference beetween mobile and non-mobile versions then you can do two differend things:

1. make adaptive css styles by using @media query.
2. In your view's render method make your check, which you specified in ansver, and based on its results change template to mobile version

But if you want explicitly define url for mobile devices, you should check for mobile users in your router like this:

```
routes: function(){
    if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
    {
        return  {
            // routes for mobile devices
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return {
            // routes for non-mobile devices
        };          
    }
}
```